# scala foldLeft with map of maps

Tags: scala

I have a Map which is like

`val v = Map("A" -> Map("C" -> "D", "F" -> "G"), "B" -> Map("C" -> "E", "M" -> "N"))`

I have to create new map which will have list of value maps and their parents, so my resultant map will look like

`Map("C" -> List(Map("A" -> Map("C" -> "D", "F" -> "G"), "B" -> Map("C" -> "E", "M" -> "N")), "F" -> List(Map("A" -> Map("C" -> "D", "F" -> "G")), "M" -> List("B" -> Map("C" -> "E", "M" -> "N")))`

can this be possible with foldleft. I know this is confusing but any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it can be done with a `foldLeft`.

I don't know why you have Lists in there, because each `List` has exactly one `Map` as an element. Not more, not less.

Anyways.

I use the fold over the `values` (which are the maps) of `v`, so I can access the `keys` of those maps faster. I throw away all `keys` which are already in `acc`, so there won't be any duplicate computation. (`elem.keys.filter(!acc.isDefinedAt(_))`).

Then for each `key` that is not yet in our result `acc`, traverse the original `v` and look where it occurs as a `key` in the value maps. (`v.filter{case (k, map) => map.isDefinedAt(key)})`)

Then put the filtered maps in a List and add them with their corresponding keys to `acc`.

**Side note**: *maps of maps, keys of values, keys, values ...* I'm not sure how I can explain this better without even confusing myself... I don't even know what I should highlight..

```
val v = Map("A" -> Map("C" -> "D", "F" -> "G"), "B" -> Map("C" -> "E", "M" -> "N"))

val result = v.values.foldLeft(Map.empty[String, List[Map[String, Map[String, String]]]])((acc, elem) => {
 val nextEntries = elem.keys.filter(!acc.isDefinedAt(_)).map(key => 
   key -> List(v.filter{case (k, map) => map.isDefinedAt(key)}))
 acc ++ nextEntries
})

println(result) //Map(C -> List(Map(A -> Map(C -> D, F -> G), B -> Map(C -> E, M -> N))), F -> List(Map(A -> Map(C -> D, F -> G))), M -> List(Map(B -> Map(C -> E, M -> N))))
```